# How to hide or disable Cancel button in IsWix Installer?

Tags: c#, user-interface, wix, windows-services

I'm using `IsWix` to build installer for windows service (C#).

1. Is it possible to hide/disable/delete the `Repair/Change` buttons?
2. Is it possible to change GUI (license, image etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer uses the ARPNOMODIFY property to hide the change button and the ARPNOREPAIR property to hide the repair button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpnomodify
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpnorepair

The IsWiX template puts the icon, jpeds and EULAs in the Resources folder for easy updating.  For additional changes you need to write code in the UI.wxs fragement.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It helped me.